# Access File Descriptor after fork-exec

Tags: c++, unix, exec, parent-child, file-descriptor

I am doing a class project in which I gotta open a file (which contains paths) and create several child process (which will inherit the file descriptor). The point is, I gotta do an exec to the children and, in the children code (after the exec) use that file descriptor to access the file.
Is there a way access the file descriptor from the child without using exec with the file descriptor as one of the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean "do an exec to the children"? Which process will call `exec`, the parent or the child? And what should the call to `exec` do?

Comment: "do an exec to the children" means I will call execvp on the children.
What the exec does does not matter (or so do I think) it will just call another program made by me.
What I want to know is if there's a way to share (both programs knowing) the same file descriptor, and being able to access it from the child.

Comment: A child (in this context) is a *process*, not an *executable file*. Are you sure you need exec? Have you done simpler things with `fork` before?

Comment: A child is a process, yeah, I know it; and exec replaces the code of the program from which it's called with the code of the program you want, and that's exactly what I want to do. But I need both programs, the parent and the children to share a concrete file descriptor, being the children able to access to it.

And yep, I've used fork and exec previously without any problem.

Comment: (I think we have a language problem.) If you create the file descriptor before the forks, then the parent and the children will share it, and the children will have access to it.

Comment: Yeah, most likely :P Alright, yeah, I know that, but after that, how can I access it from the children? I mean, there's no variable with which I can access it nor can I use an argument (prerequisite).

Comment: ??? Show us code, please.

Comment: I don't know what's not understandable here. You normally use exec after fork in child process. What don't you understand @Beta? And instead of running both processes from one file, he wants (or has) to have them in two separate file (whence the exec). Before fork he opens a file. Now the question is how code in separate file can know which file descriptor (as concrete number) is the one passed open from parent to child (through both fork and exec).

Comment: I don't see any other option than checking from `fd = 3` with `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` (this will return `EBADFD`, when fd is not opened for you). But if parent closes any of `stdout`, `stdin` or `stderr`, then this one will fail badly. And still you will not know wich fd does what.